# Caching data locally (in browser) received using Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, socket.io

**Is there a library/project which smooths over the process of caching some json data in the browser when using socket.io?**  I guess ***what I really mean is***, is there a github/opensource project already out there focused on this task so that a developer could more or less drop it into any socket.io project?

For example, let's say I am getting tabular data for a page and the data is received by using socket.io.  I want the data to remain cached so that I can save a server request if the user reloads the browser.

Additionally, I'd want this to happen more or less without me having to manually create cache variables, like: http://davidwalsh.name/cache-ajax . I want the socket.io cache library to be able to do this for me.

I want to occasionally & easily be able to clear the cache if it changed on the server. So, let's assume for that what I'm looking for has a method for analyzing timestamps on when the remote data was modified.  What I mean is, let's assume for now that there is a way of notifying the browser when database table/rows/documents have been modified so that it knows when to clear the socket.io cache (perhaps sending meta information about database table modify timestamps along with data requests or maybe with an occasional comet-type message).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use local storage? Read about it from [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

It is easier to use.

To set value

```
localStorage[ 'key' ] = strValue;
```

To retrieve

```
strVal = localStorage[ 'key' ];
```

Yup, just simple associative arrays

Comment: I want a library which will handle details like that for me.  Edited my question to fine tune my question, thanks.

Comment: There is no library that I know of.

Comment: Hmm I wonder if there is a version of this that meshes with socket.io: https://github.com/paulirish/jquery-ajax-localstorage-cache